# Glassfish: serve files uploaded by users (Alternate docroot relative Webapp)

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, glassfish

In my webapp i have users uploading files (images and documents) that should later be available to other users.

Here is the glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD 
    GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
    "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
<property name="alternatedocroot_1"
         value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:/glassfish31/glassfish/domains/domain1" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

It works, but I want to deploy the app on other systems (linux/windows).

Q1: Is there any way of avoiding writing the full path here, atleast make it portable over linux/windows?

Q2: When uploading the files I use primefaces and store the file to disc using a hardcoded string that points to the same dir as above.

```
public static final String ALTERNATE_DOC_ROOT_1 = "C:/glassfish31/glassfish/domains/domain1/uploads";
```

Is there some API that lets my code lookup the absolute path of the alternate docroot so it can store files in it?

Comment: did you ever work out the answer to Q2?

Comment: no, I made it a configurable parameter in the database. that is fetched in an eager JSF bean on startup

Answer (score 0):

Q1: simply replacing the absolute path with a dot made it default to :

```
C:/glassfish31/glassfish/domains/domain1

<property name="alternatedocroot_1"
     value="from=/uploads/* dir=." />
```

So i guess that will work on linux also, but havnt tested